# Why is 50% height not covering fully in html

Tags: html, css

So I have one outer div, and inside this div i want to divide into two equal height div something like:

[image]

However, in my HTML document, i have the following:

[image]

As shown, even if i equally divide each div with 50% height, there seemed to be some tiny gap left. Why is this happening?

**Edit:
What if i add two child div in the top portion, giving them a height of 100%?**

[image]

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

.top {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Added child divs*/
.child_1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.child_2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <div class = "top">
      <div class = "child_1">

      </div>
      <div class = "child_2">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is actually going outside because you did not reset the `box-sizing` property to include `border` and `padding` into calculation of outer size.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.top {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="top">

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Info about it :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
>
> The `box-sizing` CSS property sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated.

See also:

> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/
>
> The `box-sizing` property in CSS controls how the [box model](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) is handled for the element it applies to.

**Edit** after question was edited and rephrased:

The inner box are sized from the inner height available (minus padding and/or border if any) ,children on the second level are not size from the main parent's height. You need then here to mind that difference. You can push the the second inner box of 2px down , average size missing from the borders of the parent.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}

.top {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    /* see me */
    border-color:green;
}

.bottom {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    /* see me */
    border-color:cyan;
}

/*Added child divs*/
.child_1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    /* see me */
    border-color:blue;
}

.child_2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    /* add those borders to go through */
    margin-top:2px;
    /* see me */
    border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <div class = "top">
      <div class = "child_1">

      </div>
      <div class = "child_2">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, now what if in the top portion, i add two more child divs and giving them a height of 100%, now the second child would overflow to the bottom which is expected, but the gap then occurs again. is it possible to get rid of the gap to in this case? It would be as in I will give animation to the child divs in which the second child div would rise up to the top with translateY(-100%). I've updated my post.

Comment: make the 2 children float or .top display:flex ... so they stand side by side ... while testing give different border colors to your div to see where they stand. 100% + 100% is 200%, the second overflows from its parent ...

Comment: actually i wouldn't want them side by side.

Comment: so it overflows off the box and overflow the second row . If that is another question make another question before any answers here looks weird and far away from the question ;)

Comment: the second box overflowing gets the size from the inner box it it belongs to excluding the borders, this the gap your are missing,  about 2 px missing (border of its own parent and border of the second row. `.child_2 {margin-top:2px;}`

Answer (score 0):

in CSS add the code below.

`* { box-sizing: border-box; }`